# VBA in Excel 2007/2010 GUI Hidden Sheet Query Refresh

Tags: vba, excel

Hi First Post   and hope someone can help as it is causing hair loss.

I design GUI's using excel and access.  2003 i never had a problem  but since updating to 2007/2010   i have having a problem with a seamingly simple thing.

In 2003  i could refresh a query on a very hidden sheet using

```
Sheet2.Range("a1").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

in 2007 / 2010   i cannot do this.   It works if i cut and paste the query off the 2003 sheets into 2007 / 2010  Perfectly  but not if it is a query i build in 2007 / 2010.

The recorder spits out

```
Range("Table_Query_from_MS_Access_Database_1[[#Headers],[Trans_ID]]").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

Which the page has to be selected first to run

so logically i have tried

```
Sheet2.Range("a1").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

which selects the position of the query first    again wont work  it fails at the Sheet2.Range("a1").Select   part

Then i logically tried

```
Sheet2.Range("a1").Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

again  this doesnt work

```
Sheet2.Range("Table_Query_from_MS_Access_Database_1[[#Headers],Trans_ID]]") _
      .Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

This Also doesnt work

All i want to do is refresh a query on a very hidden sheet

Using screen.update = false  then unhide    macro   hide  screen update = true   isnt really ideal as i want to stop the end user from getting to this query as it is part of a logon System in excel      i just cant work out a way to refresh the query on the hidden sheet which was a simple task in 2003.

Please help my hair loss

Thanks

Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select does not work on a very hidden sheet.
Try it without the select -
 
Sheet2.Range("a1").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Comment: :O it works Hidden    : (  )  It works Very hidden      Thank you so much    !!!!     this was driving me insane      woods for the trees  i might get some sleep tonight as i been trying everything to try and create a more seamless GUI in excel 2007    was starting to think M$ were going to start to force ppl to use them horrable pivot tables,     now i can just use my fav sumproduct(--((  summary way  for my GUI reports        I really Mean it  Thank You :)